# Changing externally shared hyperlinks format

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, hyperlink, formatting, external-users

Just wondering if anyone knows is there a way to change the format of the way documents are shared from SharePoint to external users.

It works great by sending the guest hyperlink etc. but is there a way to format that hyperlink to make it look less messy (its a very long link) or even a way to replace the hyperlink with a logo/symbol etc.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest link you can get for a document can be found when you open the **Ellipsis (...)** on the document or folder as the URL found in the dialog box formats the direct path to the document. 
`(https://<server>/<site>/<library>/<folder>/<filename>)`

Teach your users to open and use this link when copying and pasting a direct link to a file/folder. Remember you need to be outside a folder to get the link to it. ;-)

(Applies to SharePoint 2013)